# Failed to read file attributes for Images.xcassets in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode9-beta

I have old project that is running in Xcode 8 fine but when i am trying to run the project in Xcode 9 beta version I am getting the error

> Failed to read file attributes for Images.xcassets

[image]

Comment: Might be a bug since it is in beta version

Comment: You should check your group name and full path in File inspector.

Comment: I have checked the path is correct. Actually the project creation year is 2012. Now for the latest project imageAsset name updated with "Assets.xcassets". As I mentioned it is an old project, Earlier the name of imageAsset was "Images.xcassets". That could be the reason of the error

Comment: check the path is correct or not

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I have checked the path is correct. If there is path issue then it should not work in Xcode 8 too.

Comment: clean the derived data and run once

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Still same error after deleting the derived data and clean the project

Comment: Can you right click on the Image.xcassets then show it in finder and tell us if the folder is called Images.xcassets or images.xcasset ?

Comment: Images.xcassets

Comment: and the full path of Images.xcassets ?

Comment: Thanks guys for your help! Issue has been resolved by removing the reference  of Images.xcassets and adding it again.

Answer (score 71):

Removing the reference of Images.xcassets and adding it again in Project resolved the error.

Comment: I am running into this as well. What do you mean exactly when you say 'removing the reference'?

Comment: When you delete any file you will get 2 option remove reference or delete file from project. In case of remove reference file will be in your project but not in your Xcode navigator

Comment: @ArvindKumar solved, Now you can accept your answer as correct.

Comment: This fixed it for me as well

Answer (score 0):

I did face the same errors what you've but I just fixed it following ways-

1. Delete the project's derived data
2. Exit Xcode and open it again

Answer (score 0):

Check your "Full path" in inspector and path in Finder, probably they are different.
I also had this issue. on my pc was ../Development/MyProject/.. and ../development/MyProject/.. so in that was problem

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is related to bug of cocoapods causes compilation error. To solve this, you can try add this to your podfile to the bottom level :

Change the target name according to your target name

post_install do |installer|

```
copy_pods_resources_path = "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-XXXTARGETNAMEXXX/Pods-XXXTARGETNAMEXXX-resources.sh"
string_to_replace = '--compile "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}"'
assets_compile_with_app_icon_arguments = '--compile "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}" --app-icon "${ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME}" --output-partial-info-plist "${BUILD_DIR}/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist"'
text = File.read(copy_pods_resources_path)
new_contents = text.gsub(string_to_replace, assets_compile_with_app_icon_arguments)
File.open(copy_pods_resources_path, "w") {|file| file.puts new_contents }
```

end

Answer (score -1):

It fixes for me by update to latest Cocoapods:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods --pre
```

Comment: Make sure Images.xassets path is correct, especially you git clone or copy the project from others, otherwise you have to select correct local path first in storyboard.